# PHP Soap server behaves oddly when request is large

Tags: php, apache, soap

We have a Soap Server in PHP that receives a file in Base64.

We recently changed the production Server to another computer. After changing the Server, now the request returns error when the file sent is big, but the requests work when file is small. The same requests with big files works on development server and on test server, but not on production server.

I debug the server code, and it behaves oddly when the file sent is big. Database queries return false instead of table row. The same query works well when it is run directly on the database, but not on php code.

When the file sent is small, everything works fine, database queries return the table row and the script works fine and the file is saved on server.

I tried to compare test server and production server on phpinfo().

I didn't find much difference.

Production server has LAMP, CentOS, Apache, Mysql and PHP.

I tried to raise memory_limit on php.ini until 3G, and -1. I tried to raise post_max_size to 1G. I tried to raise upload_max_filesize to 1G.

But it is not working yet.

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't know why it failed only on production server. I optimized the code, now it works on production server.